# HTTP Download Time

Tags: apache, http, ubuntu, download

I"m running a Apache2 server on Ubuntu 11.10 and I"d like to time HTTP Downloads.

Currently, the time is set up such that I start it externally and I tail the access log to conclude it.

I was wondering if there's a way to do this entirely on the Apache server end.

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you just add `%D` to LogFormat: http://www.ducea.com/2008/02/06/apache-logs-how-long-does-it-take-to-serve-a-request/  .  For client side timing, I run `time curl --silent http://mysite.com/ > /dev/null`

Comment: I forgot to add. I *have* to use the browser to download the file

Comment: Then you can add `%D` to `LogFormat` in your apache conf, yeah?

Comment: It causes total request processing time to be logged in your access log.  Check out the link I posted in the first comment.

Comment: You should post that as an answer. I just tried it and it works perfectly. Post the answer and I'll upvote+accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `%D` to `LogFormat` in your httpd.conf.  Then you'll find timing info in your access log.

More detail at http://www.ducea.com/2008/02/06/apache-logs-how-long-does-it-take-to-serve-a-request/

Answer (score 0):

I use [apache benchmark](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html) for raw load testing. Check [this page](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/website-load-speed-performace-testing-tools.html) out for other methods of measurement.

If you're interested how your server performs in the long run, maybe you should install [munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/) with the httpresponsetime -plugin. The default installation shows you a lot of useful information about the status of your server.